# creating a holiday programme?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been set a task and it is the following, I was wondering would my code would work?

write a program to ask for a name and an age.
when both values have been entered, check if the person is the right
age to on an 18-30 holiday(they must be over 18 and under 31

```
name = input("What is your name? ")
age = int(input("How old are you ? "))

if 18 <= age < 31:

    print("Hello",name,"welcome to this holiday.".format(name))
else:
    print("Sorry",name,"you are not old enough to go on this holiday. ")
```

Comment: Why didn't you run it on your machine first before asking here? Are you facing any error?

Comment: I would remove `.format(name)`.

Comment: this question is better suited at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

well actually it works but you don't need the format part

```
name = input("What is your name? ") 
age = int(input("How old are you ? "))

if age >=18 and age <31:
    print("Hello",name,"welcome to this holiday.")
else:
    print("Sorry",name,"you are not old enough to go on this holiday. ")
```

if you want to use format you can do this

```
print("Hello {name} welcome to this holiday.".format(name=name))
```

Answer (score 0):

Code works perfect, but you have a useless format

Just use format, not the `,` part.

```
name = input("What is your name? ")
age = int(input("How old are you ? "))

if 18 <= age < 31:

    print("Hello {name} welcome to this holiday.".format(name))
else:
    print("Sorry {name} you are not old enough to go on this holiday.".format(name))
```

Or if you don't like to do format

```
name = input("What is your name? ") 
age = int(input("How old are you ? "))

if age >=18 and age <31:
    print("Hello",name,"welcome to this holiday.")
else:
    print("Sorry",name,"you are not old enough to go on this holiday. ")
```